# Creating stairs that go up with each step and form a circular staircase

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a circular staircase. Each step (objects are rectangular) appears when I press the space key, and it is slightly above and at a different angle from the previous one. So, I'm attempting to create a staircase that spirals upward. I have an object pool, and I'm dragging the object from there, providing the necessary position and angle, but I can't seem to achieve what I want. In some parts of the staircase, it looks like objects are stacked on top of each other. In short, to summarize, I'm trying to create a staircase similar to the one in the game "Climb the Stair." Can you help me with this?

```
public PoolManager PoolManager;
public float Radius = 1f;
public float HeightIncrement=0.0035f;
public float CurrentAngle;

private void Update()
{
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
CreateStair();
}
}

private void CreateStair()
{
float radians = Mathf.Deg2Rad * CurrentAngle;

float xPosition = Radius * Mathf.Cos(radians);
float yPosition = CurrentAngle * HeightIncrement;
float zPosition = Radius * Mathf.Sin(radians);

GameObject stair = PoolManager.GetPooledObject(0);
if (stair != null)
{
stair.transform.position = new Vector3(xPosition, yPosition, zPosition);

CurrentAngle += 10.0f;
}
}
```

Comment: You would also need to rotate the new stair according to the angle. I would also decouple the angle from the height - maybe consider an `int StairIndex` from which you compute the angle and height...

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, but I couldn't do what you said. :(

Comment: "Couldn't do"? What did you try, where did you fail?